# Pandas dataframe style not blank different columns

Tags: python, pandas, styles

I have seen multiple answers on this topic but none answer exactly what I'm looking for : different colors for different columns in a dataframe

Here is a random dataframe which I color in the following way :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

example = [['test1',1,2,'',''],['test2',3,4,'',''],['test3','','',5,6],['test4','','',7,8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(example, columns=['column1','column2','column3','column4','column5'])

def highlight_col(x):
            # if x == 0.0:
            # blue 0= 'background-color: #ACE5EE '
                blue = 'background-color: lightblue '
                red = 'background-color: #ffcccb'
                df = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
                df.iloc[:, 1:3] = blue #if x else 'white'
                df.iloc[:, 3:6] = red #if x else 'white'
                return df 

df.style.apply(highlight_col,axis=None)
```

[image: current table]

While this highlights the correct columns, I only want them colored when the cell **is not blank** thus have the two bottom rows of column2 and column3 white and the two top rows of column4 and column5 white like so :

[image: aimed table]

Please let me know if I'm not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask your output value using the original `df`, this solution is not very dynamic though:

```
def highlight_col(x):
            # if x == 0.0:
            # blue 0= 'background-color: #ACE5EE '
                blue = 'background-color: lightblue '
                red = 'background-color: #ffcccb'
                df2 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
                df2.iloc[:, 1:3] = blue #if x else 'white'
                df2.iloc[:, 3:6] = red #if x else 'white'
                return df2.where(df.ne(''))

df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)
```

Output:

[image]

A more dynamic method:

```
colors = {'column2': 'lightblue', 'column3': 'lightblue',
          'column4': '#ffcccb', 'column5': '#ffcccb'}

def highlight_col(s):
    return s.mask(s.ne(''), f'background-color: {colors.get(s.name, "none")}')

df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway , both methods worked indeed. I ended up using the less dynamic method because I needed my `axis=None` in order to add the parameter 
 `.format(precision=2)` However I will keep the second method in mind which seems shorter and more practical :)